# RegEx capture group where delimiter can appear in the group

Tags: regex

I need a regex that will capture the following:

```
foo-bar-fort-worth-tx

1st group: (foo-bar) 2nd group: (fort-worth) 3rd group: (tx)
```

I'm having trouble since the delimiter '-' can also appear in the capture group. Luckly, I think there will be at most '-' in each capture group.

Here's my regex:

```
^(.+)-(.+)-[a-zA-Z]{2}$
```

However, it's not working as expected. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your pattern. When you use a capturing group such as `(.+)`, the regex will try and match (and capture) anything (`.`) as much as possible due to the greediness of `+`. See [here](https://regex101.com/r/e8szsm/2) for the pattern and check the [debugger too](https://regex101.com/r/e8szsm/2/debugger). As it matches anything, it will match up until the end of the string. The pattern then asks for a `-`, so the regex has to backtrack until it finds the `-`, and then stops. Hence you end up with:

```
Group 1.    0-18    `foo-bar-fort-worth`
```

---

Use the following expression which uses negated character sets to match and capture the patterns you described:

```
^([^-]+-[^-]+)-([^-]+-[^-]+)-(.*)$
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/e8szsm/1).

```
Group 1.    0-7     `foo-bar`
Group 2.    8-18    `fort-worth`
Group 3.    19-21   `tx`
```